# Confusion with negative voltages in this opamp circuit

Tags: voltage, operational-amplifier

I want to use a circuit like below to amplify a photodiode:

[image]
(taken from [this](https://www.thorlabs.com/newgrouppage9.cfm?objectgroup_id=9020) page)

But it requires negative voltage.

Can I use the following circuit I modified instead with a positive supply only:

[image]

And if correct, how can I couple the output to an ADC input?

Comment: What's the supply voltage? What is the op-amp part number? If the op-amp saturation voltage is low enough and the supply voltage is big enough (like twice the 3.3v you are using for reference), yes. This should work. Bear in mind that 3.3v must be able to sink and source to be able to use it like this. What are you using for that?

Comment: Need lots more detail. What power supplies do you have? Need something higher than 3.3 for the opamp to make this work. Is 3.3 enough bias? What's the expected photocurrent?

Comment: About your ADC question: include in your question the ADC's input voltage range. For example, a microcontroller's internal ADC might use its +Vdd (3.3V?) as the ADC reference voltage, so it accepts input voltage range from 0V up to +3.3V. Some ADC might allow you to apply a DC reference voltage to a pin, or select various reference voltages with a command..

Comment: LM2776 voltage inverter currently sells for ~$1 on digikey, and there are various schematics online for photodiode bipolar power supplies (e.g. https://github.com/OpenSiPM/sipm-bias-control/tree/master/power-supply).  If you want it referenced to ground, aren't making 100k units and needing to save every dollar, consider just adding a negative voltage rail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *But it requires negative voltage.*

No it doesn't; it's giving you the option of tying the photodiode anode to ground/0 volts or, if you want fairly high-speed operation, you can apply a negative bias voltage. If you don't need a high-speed (in the MHz) response, then ignore the option of using a negative supply to bias the photodiode and just connect its anode to ground.

> *Can I use the following circuit I modified instead with a positive
> supply only*

Stick with the first circuit is my advice and, ensure the following: -

- If your op-amp **doesn't** use a negative rail then, you'll need to ensure that it has the capability of running both inputs at 0 volts AND, that the output can fall to significantly close to 0 volts. Typically an LM324 can do this but, there are better/other choices.
- If your op-amp **does** use a negative rail then, you can also use this for biasing the photodiode anode. It's your choice.

Comment: Oh woow then I completely misunderstood it I thought what you call an option was a switch.

Comment: @floppy380 the notes under the picture on Thorlabs page kind of indicate that you have the option.

Comment: @floppy380 are we done with this question and answer session now?

Comment: Of course, I forgot to select. Im planning to open another question soon would you mind if I remind you here? Its related using a photo diode to monitor average power from a short pulse laser and measuring it without saturating the photodiode.

Comment: @floppy380 please do remind me and thanks.

Comment: Hello again. I finally could write the question. Looking forward to your feedback/answer. Here is my new question: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/694976/determining-the-maximum-input-power-of-a-photosensor-for-a-given-laser-power-inp

Answer (score 1):

Put simply, it is ok. But you need to clarify some questions:

1. The reverse bias voltage requirement of your photodiode. In the circuit below, the PD is reverse-biased 3.3V. the reverse bias is mostly for reducing the capacitance of the PD, to get high-speed and low-noise TIA. Common telecom photodiode is ok with 3.3v reverse bias, but some PDs, especially some large active area PDs need higher voltage. you can check the voltage-capacitance curve.
2. The op-amp supply voltage; the opamp input common range and output common range. 3.3V is your input and output common range. 3.3V + (Ip+Id) * Rf is the output voltage. make sure they are in the op amp's specified range.
3. The output is referenced to 3.3V (from 3.3V to higher voltage), check with the ADC input range, the coupling may be very simple(resister divider, direct into the ADC) or complex(another op-amp is needed). for better performance, you may need a single-ended to differential conversion using a fully differential amplifier. you may refer to the ADC spec. Usually they should have an example of the input coupling(DC/AC).

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you have to decide is the photodetector selection. The reason you get a choice in photodetcctor biasing in the app note's sketchy, conceptual schematic is that it's intended to apply to both photovoltaic and photoconductive detectors.  A connection to ground would suffice for photovoltaic. It's not clear why you're concerned about the ADC connection. You don't need a BNC connection unless the ADC is some distance away. If it is, you're getting off on the wrong foot.