# Determining the maximum input power of a photosensor for a given laser power input

Tags: datasheet, maximum-ratings, photosensor

I need to measure the average power of a 1550nm pulsed laser output using a photodiode. The datasheet of the Thorlabs FDG03 photodiode can be found [here](https://www.thorlabs.com/drawings/824ce44711746f1e-9340AE74-D288-E0FC-533B7E99721B92C5/FDG03-SpecSheet.pdf) (or if these links fail, the product page with relevant links is [here](https://www.thorlabs.com/thorproduct.cfm?partnumber=FDG03)). I'm also planning to use the recommended circuit with Rload = 50 Ohm load and with 2.5V or 3V bias:

[image]

In my case, the pulsed laser's repetition rate is 1kHz, pulse width is 1ns and I can set the laser average power. At [this](https://www.thorlabs.com/newgrouppage9.cfm?objectgroup_id=1285) page under "Pulse Calculations" tab, there is a formula which calculates the peak power of a pulsed laser as:

[image]

[image]

I'm trying to figure out what should be the maximum average power of the laser which does not damage the photodiode. My confusion is should I just look at the average power or the peak power.

The photodiode datasheet does not give detail about maximum optical input power. But it gives the maximum current as 5mA:

[image]

The responsivity is given as 0.85 A/W so I calculate the maximum power as:

Pin_max = 1000mW / 850mA * 5mA = 11mW

So if I'm not wrong the maximum optical input power of the photodiode is 11mW.

So in my case not to exceed this, I need to set the laser peak power to 11mW? If I do that and follow the equations below:

[image]

Pavg = 11mW * 1000Hz * 0.000000001 = 11nW

Does that mean I need to set the average max power of the pulsed laser to 11nW not to damage the photodiode? It is extremely small and I'm not sure if my way of doing is correct.

Comment: Excuse me, but if I have interpreted the formula correctly, the peak power is:  11mW * 1ms/1ns= 11kW. Since I= Res*Pavg, I get : I=9.35mA.

Comment: The coaxial cable "external" wire is not "grounded"?

Comment: What is the beam angle of the laser and, at what distance is it relative to the photodiode?

Comment: Just from experience and without looking at the datasheet, you will have to be very careful with that laser. At 1 KHz/1ns it will be very easy to evaporate the metallization right off the detector face regardless of the maximum photocurrent  current rating. I recommend attenuating the laser as low as you can get away with.

Comment: @Andyaka That is the question actually. How much  attenuation I need(by means of distance or sphere attenuator ect.) not to damage the laser. For example, if I set the laser rep rate to 1kHz and average power to 1mW; after this stage how much optical power attenuation I need not to damage the laser? I just want to be sure how much attenuation I need before the photodiode.

Comment: @user1850479  I first need to set it to a certain low average power and then couple it to the photodiode. The problem is if I attenuate it 1 million times, the average becomes 11nW and this cannot be measured by optical power meter.

Comment: @floppy380 Can you edit the question to (a) describe the issue with calculating how much attenuation is needed (b) include what the minimum power level the available optical power meter can measure (c) any limitations of the setup in terms of how far away the the photodiode can be placed and what sphere attenuator is available.

Comment: I opened a new question: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/695059/how-to-estimate-the-optical-power-given-the-scope-reading-for-this-scenario

Comment: Start illuminating the diode at low power and gradually increase it until you can take your measurements. Do not go brighter than needed and do not focus tightly onto the diode.

Comment: @user1850479 Yes I can do that. But my problem is about relating my data in scope to the input power. I dont know if I'm exceeding diode specs. Yes I see the pulse peak is increasing by illumination but how to interpret this so to be sure Im not exceeding specs. See my new question. (Im actually interested in measuring the average power at the end of the day.)

Comment: You know that your diode produces X electrons per photon.  You are measuring the number of electrons and thus know the energy in each pulse and the power (energy per time).  Can't you just take the average of your power measurement to get the average power?

Comment: I can do that by using RC LP filter right? Also I can increase the rep rate to 3MegHz. But this question is about Im wondering whether Im exceeding the max input optical peak power. I dont care about measuring peak power just dont want to damage the diode.  Do you get where I am stuck at?

Comment: Ah you mean finding the peak power from the average using rep rate formula?

Comment: So I should translate the scope waveform to current waveform by dividing the resistor; then I will integrate the current to obtain total current and then divide it by the period 0.001sec to obtain the average current and them use 0.85A/W to calculate the average power? After that I will use this formula https://i.stack.imgur.com/TxNqn.png to estimate the optical input peak power?

Comment: @floppy380 - Hi, I see that you have changed the part number of the photodiode, but the link I added to the previous photodiode's product page (to help users, due to the problem of the expiring Thorlabs datasheet PDF links) is now incorrect, as it was not changed. Therefore I will update that one to match the updated photodiode model FDG03 in the question.

Comment: The vendor does not spec a maximum peak optical power so there is no possible way you can calculate if you are using a safe optical power. Why do you need to know this?

Comment: @user1850479 To attenuate the pulsed laser not to damage the photodiode. But how much attenuation is dictated by damage threshold for pulsed input. But it is not stated. If I attenuate tooo much then the signal will be buried in noise. But what is the upper limit, I dont know. They dont even provide max pulse energy it can handle.

Comment: Haven't you already posted very high SNR measurements taken with the photodiode? Seems a little late to calculate how attenuation you need now that you have experimentally determined that you're below the damage threshold.

Comment: @user1850479 What do u mean? Thats not the correct way. Just because I see the pulse doesnt mean its not being damaged. I need some treshold value.

Comment: With nanosecond pulses you damage by vaporization. If your diode had left the solid phase you would not see any output. However, if you must have a specification, buy a device that has a specification for illumination with nanosecond pulses.

Answer (score 0):

> My confusion is should I just look at the average power or the peak power.

The *Example Calculation* part of the Pulse Calculations tab of the [page](https://www.thorlabs.com/newgrouppage9.cfm?objectgroup_id=1285) shows a calculation where:

- The energy per pulse is 11.8 pJ, which is described as *seems low*.
- The peak pulse power is calculated as 1.18 kW
- Which results in the conclusion:

  > It is ***not safe*** to use the detector to measure this pulsed laser emission, since the peak power of the pulses is >5 orders of magnitude higher than the detector's maximum peak optical input power.

Which suggests the peak power needs to be used.

> The photodiode datasheet does not give detail about maximum optical input power. But it gives the maximum current as **5mA**:

While the text in the question says the maximum current is *5 mA*, the table has *10 mA*. I assume the value of *5 mA*  is a typo, working through the calculations with a maximum current of 10 mA end up with the same maximum peak power of 11.7 mW for the photo detector.

> Does that mean I need to set the average max power of the pulsed laser to 11nW not to damage the photodiode?

Is it possible to attenuate how much of the laser power reaches the detector?

[Pulsed Lasers Introduction to Power and Energy Calculations](https://www.thorlabs.com/images/tabimages/Laser_Pulses_Power_Energy_Equations.pdf) contains:

> Since photodiodes typically have relatively maximum peak optical input power limits, the laser pulses should be **attenuated** as necessary to protect the sensor.

**Edit:**

After getting a downvote realised that this answer doesn't necessarily address the following:

> The photodiode datasheet does not give detail about maximum optical input power.

Perhaps there is a flaw in my thinking behind calculating the *peak pulse power* and you should ask Thorlabs about the peak pulse power allowed.

@Andy aka made a good point in a comment on the question that the beamwidth of the laser, and how far away the 7.1 mm<sup>2</sup> active area of the FDG03 photodiode is from the laser, will affect how much laser power is received by the FDG03.